# How can I add default selected Choose a field option to my drop-down in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-helper

In my signup I have `Choose a Question` drop-down:Code below

```
<%= f.select("question_id", Question.all.collect {|p| [ p.body, p.id ] }])) %>
```

and I want to get the output like below

```
<select name="question" id="login_fields_question" class="signup_fields"  >
<option value="choosequestion" selected="selected" style="font-style:italic;">Choose a question ...</option>
<option value="1"> What is your pet name?</option> 
<option value="2">What is the name of your best friend from childhood?</option>
<option value="3">What was the name of your first teacher?</option>
<option value="4">What is the name of your manager at your first job?</option>
<option value="5">What was your first phone number?</option>
<option value="6">What is your vehicle registration number?</option>
```

With the code `f.select` I could get all questions from database but How can I add `Choose a question ...` option to my drop-down? which will be shown on default and could give output as above HTML code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `:prompt => "Choose a question ..."` option?

I hope help you!

Hugs!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
= f.select "question_id", Question.all.collect {|p| [ p.body, p.id ] }, include_blank: "Choose a question ..."
```